# How to recreate this gradient in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

[image]

Need to recreate this gradient in Illustrator. I tried the various gold/metallic gradients, but nothing close to this, and not as random.
Is it achiveable in any other software? Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a gradient It's a series of solid filled circles. You may be able to get close, but you won't be able to match the way color is dispersed.

I'd blur the image....

[image]

This way color shows more than the divisive circles.

Then sample the colors and build a gradient....

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. The attached is a vector and I tried picking the colours from each circle, but each solid fill shows as the gradient and not a solid colour. That is why I thought maybe there's some way of applying the gradient to a series of circles.

Comment: @Mdd7725 Oh there may be then. It looks like solid filled circles here. Especially because of how colors are dispersed. It *can't* be one gradient applied to all the circles. Maybe each circle is too subtle. If they all have the same gradient, can't you drag the gradient swatch from the **Gradient Panel** to the **Swatch Panel** to save it?

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator you can:
Make new swatches of the colours in your reference image.
Select your circles and make it a live paint object.
With the live paint group selected, use the bucket tool and your left right arrow keys to cycle through your swatches and fill your circles. 
You can hold down your mouse button/stylus and draw across multiple circles to fill them with the same colour/swatch.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you can pick up the gradient using Illustrator's eyedropper tool, I would draw a rectangle the size of your artboard and fill the rectangle with the gradient.

Then draw a second rectangle of the same size and fill it with white.

Now draw a circle on top of the white rectangle at the location of one of the circles in your sample image.  Select the white rectangle and the new circle, and use the pathfinder tool to "Exclude" or "Minus Front."

This creates a compound path, which causes Illustrator to treat the circles as if they were holes cut through the white rectangle, allowing the gradient-filled rectangle at the bottom of the stack to show through.

If you use the "Exclude" command, you can create all of the circles first, and use the Exclude tool on all of them at once. Make sure that all of the circles are on layers above the white rectangle, and that you select all of the circles AND the white rectangle before using the Exclude command.